# Sharepoint: Retrieve info on assigned user policy

Tags: sharepoint

Case:

- Create a User Policy in SharePoint 2010 Web Application Management: assign 'Full read' to user XXX for site YYY;
- Call SiteData.asmx/GetContent for site YYY and inspect 'permissions' node.

User XXX is not assigned any permissions for site YYY according to WS call result.

1. How should I retrieve permissions of XXX for YYY via web services?
2. In which table assigned User Policy is stored in SharePoint Content database?

Comment: While your 2nd question is interesting for technical background about how SP works, **don't** read or update the DB with code. This is a black box, and thus, unsupported. Moreover, there's not guarantee this will still works with next releases.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but this would probably help me understanding why I cannot see awaited permission in scope.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's stored in any content database. A webapplication can have multiple content databases. I think webapplication scoped settings will be stored somewhere in the Config database.
I took a quick peek in there, but not sure which table to look for.

As Steve P also stated, Microsoft does not support any actions directly on the databases (except for usage analysis i believe), so be aware of that.